# How I disable or remove a global shortcut (Shift+Cmd+C)?

Tags: terminal, shortcut

I use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to delete a line in VS Code (an editor) but sometimes I accidentally hit <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> which opens a terminal.

How can I disable or remove this global <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> shortcut?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, ⇧⌘C is not a system-wide global shortcut, so it sounds like something Visual Studio is doing. It probably has a way to disable it within the application, but if not, you can try to remap it to something else (this works for **any** application where the thing you're triggering is a menu!):

- Open System Preferences, and go to the Keyboard pane.
- Head over to the Shortcuts tab, and then App Shortcuts.
- Hit the plus button, and enter the name of the "open in terminal" menu item **exactly** as it appears.
- Put in some other shortcut that you want to trigger it with.

(This works even when the menu you want to trigger doesn't usually have a shortcut. Unfortunately, it *only* works if the feature is a menu item.)

[image: osx-make-shortcut]

<sub>(Unfortunately, I probably can't release this as CC-BY-SA as per the content policy, because it's a screenshot of copyrighted proprietary software. But I don't see anyone else worrying about this, so....)</sub>

Answer (score 2):

In VS Code, type <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>, then type `shortcuts` to edit shortcuts, then type `terminal` to find the "open new terminal" command.

Right click on it → `remove shortcut` → done!

I use <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> in Chrome to inspect elements, but if the focused application is VS Code it opens a new terminal, happened to me too often.